# File into table awk

Tags: shell, awk, tags

I am trying to make a table by reading the file.

Here is an example of the code I am trying to compile:

```
FHEAD|1|PRMPC|20200216020532|1037|S
TMBPE|2|MOD
    TPDTL|3|72810|1995019|11049-|11049-|Dcto 20|0|5226468|20200216000001|20200222235959|2||1||||
        TPGRP|4|5403307
        TGLIST|5|5031472|1|||
        TLITM|6|101055590
            TPDSC|7|0|||-20||2|1|
        TPGRP|8|5403308
        TGLIST|9|5031473|0|||
    TPDTL|13|10728|1995021|11049-|11049-|Dcto 30|0|5226469|20200216000001|20200222235959|2||1||||
        TPGRP|14|5403310
        TGLIST|15|5031475|1|||
            TLITM|16|210000041
            TLITM|17|101004522
                TPDSC|113|0|||-30||2|1|
        TPGRP|114|5403309
        TGLIST|115|5031474|0|||
            TLITM|116|101047933
            TLITM|117|101004681
            TLITM|118|101028161
                TPDSC|119|0|||-25||2|1|
TPISR|214|101004225|2350|EA|20200216000000|COP|
TTAIL|1135
FTAIL|1136|1134
```

I tried to develop the code but it returns all tags in one line

```
for filename in "$input"*.dat; 
    do
    echo "$filename">>"$files"
    a=`awk -F'|' '$1=="FHEAD" && $5!=""{print $5}' "$filename"`
    b=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TPDTL" && $3!=""{print $3}' "$filename"`
    c=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TPDTL" && $4!=""{print $4}' "$filename"`
    d=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TPDTL" && $10!=""{print $10}' "$filename"`
    e=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TPDTL" && $11!=""{print $11}' "$filename"`
    f=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TPDSC" && $6!=""{print $6}' "$filename"`
    g=`awk -F'|' '$1=="TLITM" && $3!=""{print $3}' "$filename"`
```

For exemple:

```
echo -e ${d}
```

> 20200216000001 20200216000001

I wanted something like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipUFW.png).

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do add sample expected output in form of text in your question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- The frequency of appearance of the keywords like `FHEAD`, `TPDTL`, etc
  are not uniform. Use the latest one if needed.
- The number of rows should be equal to the count of `TLITM`.
- The table should be updated when `TPDSC` appears.

then would you please try the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "|"; OFS = ","}
    $1 ~ /FHEAD/ {a = $5}
    $1 ~ /TPDTL/ {b = $3; c = $4; d = $10; e = $11}
    $1 ~ /TLITM/ {f[++tlitm_count] = $3}
    $1 ~ /TPDSC/ {g = $6;
        for (i=1; i<=tlitm_count; i++) {
            print a, b, c, d, e, f[i], g
        }
        tlitm_count = 0;
    }
' *.dat
```

Output:

```
1037,72810,1995019,20200216000001,20200222235959,101055590,-20
1037,10728,1995021,20200216000001,20200222235959,210000041,-30
1037,10728,1995021,20200216000001,20200222235959,101004522,-30
1037,10728,1995021,20200216000001,20200222235959,101047933,-25
1037,10728,1995021,20200216000001,20200222235959,101004681,-25
1037,10728,1995021,20200216000001,20200222235959,101028161,-25
```

If you want the output delimiter to be a whitespace, please modify the value of `OFS`.

Comment: the solution is perfect! thank you!
however, does the print have any character limitations per line? when he tries to print the "g" in the output it gives an enter.

Comment: @RCLFA thank you for the feedback. I suppose there is no limitations of #characters per line. Would you please provide a minimal set of sample input by appending to your original post or via a download site so I can reproduce the phenomenon? BR.

Comment: when analyzing the file I noticed that they contained in field g "\n". that's why I was making a new line.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the prompt analysis.